# How cancel Timeout inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
const timers = []
const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
console.log('Starting timer2')
const timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Its works')
}, 10000)
timers.push({key:2, id:timer2})
}, 10000);
timers.push({key:1, id:timer1})

function remove(key) {
  for (i = 0; i > timers.length; i++) {
     if (timers[i].key === key) {
     timers = timers.slice(i, 1)
     clearTimeout(timers[i].id)
  }
 }
}
```

When I call the remove(key) function the code is not removing the timers as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const timers = []
const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
console.log('Starting timer2')
const timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Its works')
}, 10000)
timers.push({key:2, id:timer2})
}, 10000);
timers.push({key:1, id:timer1})

function remove(key) {
   const timer = timers.find(f => f.key === key);
   if (timer) {
     clearTimeout(timer.id);
   }
}
```